# Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Types version 10 or higher could not be found

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2022

All,

We've just been having some fun and games with the error "**Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Types version 10 or higher could not be found**".

We were migrating a .Net Framework 4.7.2 MVC application from Windows Server 2012 with SQL Server 2016 combination to one of Windows Server 2019 with SQL Server 2019.

Once migrated the application on the new environment fired up OK but this error occurred while using it.

The weird thing was all instance of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types appeared to be version 14 which made nonsense of the error message.

Comparing servers, we noted that "MicroSoft System CLR Types for SQL Server" was installed on the Windows Server 2012 web server so we added "MicroSoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2019" to the replacement server.

The issue still didn't go away.

Looking at the solution we noted that it used Version 14.0.1016.290 of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types was available but that Version 160.1000.6 was available so we updated that.

This still didn't fix the issue and we eventually realised that although we were attempting to update Microsoft.SqlServer.Types to Version 160.1000.6, the update was failing because it could not overwrite existing files and SqlServerSpatial140.dll was being left in place.

We removed all the SQLServerTypes, x86 and x84 directories which contained SqlServerSpatial140.dll then attempted to update the Nuget package again.

This still didn't work.

Then we took a look at the web.config and saw that even tough we had upgraded the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types package to Version 160.1000.6, the web.config still had it logged as

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

We update the 14 to 16 as follows

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-16.0.0.0" newVersion="16.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

That seems to have done the trick.

It seems nuts that a Nuget Package could be so problematic so maybe there's something about this solution and how it is set up which is contributing to this.

Note that we were using Visual Studio 2022 for this and the application is written in c#.

Either way I hope this experience is useful to others.